# How to trigger an Event using an ID in a Select list

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-events

I have a select list that triggers DIV tag visibility, which works great, but once I added a new select list it started conflicting with the first list.  I need to be able to use the first list to trigger the toggle event independently of any other lists in the code.

I'm to use the select list using a specific ID to properly toggle the DIV visibility but I can't seem to get it right.

```
       $(document).ready(function () {
            $("select").change(function () {
                $(this).find("option:selected").each(function () {
                    var optionValue = $(this).attr("value");
                    if (optionValue) {
                        $(".divToggle").not("." + optionValue).hide();
                        $("." + optionValue).show();
                    } else {
                        $(".divToggle").hide();
                    }
                });
            }).change();
        });
```

This is the select options:

```
<select id="transferOptions" class="form-control" name="transferoptions" aria-label="Transfer Options" tabindex="">
    <option value="fundTransferOption" selected>Select an Option</option>
    <option value="achTransfer">ACH Transfer</option>
    <option value="flashFundsTransfer">Flash Transfer</option>
</select>
<select id="ConflictingSelectOptionsAlsoCausingDIVToggling">
    <option>Choose</option>
    <option>Blah</option>
    <option>Blah 2</option>
</select>

<div class="achTransfer divToggle">On select show Thing 1</div>
<div class="flashFundsTransfer divToggle">On select show Thing 2</div>
```

I want to use the Javascript above to specifically work the select list that use the "id="transferOptions", so as I add other select lists to the code it won't conflict with the `transferOption`select list, thus triggering the DIV's in the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the select ID with its CSS selector `#transferOptions`. Also changed some logic for you to check out:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#transferOptions").change(function() {
    var optionValue = $(this).val(); // or use javascript: this.value
    $(".divToggle").hide(); // hide all .divToggle elements

    if (optionValue) { // in your example this is always true
      $("." + optionValue).show(); // show the matching element
    }
  }).change(); // trigger change after document is ready
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="transferOptions" class="form-control" name="transferoptions" aria-label="Transfer Options" tabindex="">
  <option value="fundTransferOption" selected>Select an Option</option>
  <option value="achTransfer">ACH Transfer</option>
  <option value="flashFundsTransfer">Flash Transfer</option>
</select>
<select id="ConflictingSelectOptionsAlsoCausingDIVToggling">
  <option>Choose</option>
  <option>Blah</option>
  <option>Blah 2</option>
</select>

<div class="achTransfer divToggle">On select show Thing 1</div>
<div class="flashFundsTransfer divToggle">On select show Thing 2</div>
```

Comment: I had to make additional changes to fit into my code, but it worked like a charm!  Thank!

Answer (score 1):

You can get the element that event is referring to using `event.target` instead of using `this` which in your case refers to the callback function, see example below:

```js
$('select').change(event => {
  console.log(event.target.id);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select1">
  <option>foo</option>
  <option>bar</option>
  <option>baz</option>
</select>

<select id="select2">
  <option>quux</option>
  <option>xyzzy</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!